# Is stat(2) thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, libc

Many functions of the C library are clearly marked as thread-safe or not thread-safe. For example, when I look at the manual of [gmtime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime) there is a nice table that shows which of these functions are thread-safe and which aren't.

Looking at the manual page of the [stat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function, it doesn't say one way or the other. Are functions supposed to be thread safe unless we are told otherwise?

Reading up the [POSIX Safety Concept](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX.html) did not really clearly state that a function not marked as unsafe is safe. Maybe I missed a sentence somewhere?

Comment: The functions that end in `_r` are thread safe. For example, `gmtime` is _not_ thread safe because it returns a pointer to a common/hidden global that can be overwritten by a different thread. But,`gmtime_r` _is_ thread safe because it returns a pointer that is the second argument that you pass it. Assuming you pass it a pointer that is unique for each thread (e.g. points to a variable on the stack).

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes. It's clearly documented in the `gmtime` man page, whereas, for the `stat()` function, nothing. So there is certainly a default in POSIX as mentioned by Barmar below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POSIX page on [Thread Safety](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html) says that all functions are thread-safe except the ones listed there. `stat()` is not in the list, nor are any of the variants (`lstat()`, `fstat_at()`, `fstat()`). So it should be thread-safe.

Comment: I found a [direct link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html). This is clearly spelled on that page. It's really difficult to find from the link you provided...

Comment: I didn't realize it wasn't a directly link, I copied it after I clicked on the section in the contents. They make direct linking tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The `gmtime` routines return a static pointer, which means it can be overwritten by other calls.

`Stat` does not return a pointer, you are supplying it with the structure to fill in. Therefore it cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Functions can be non-thread-safe for other reasons than returning pointers to static data.

Comment: I am prepared to believe it, but either point to an example.

Comment: Look at the list of non-safe functions linked to from my answer. Only a few of them return a static pointer.

Comment: Some of them are unsafe because they modify data that can be shared between threads, but don't use a mutex. E.g. `putc_unlocked()` or `putenv()`.